# How can I solve the "code_verifier is a required parameter" error when loging to the MercadoLibre API which uses OAuth 2.0 Protocol

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, parameters

I have this Auth python code for the Mercado Libre API:

```
url = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token'
payload = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
           'client_id': app_id,
           'client_secret': client_secret,
           'code': code_url,
           'redirect_uri': uri}
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
#json_data = response.json()

if response.status_code == 200:
    token = response.json()['refresh_token']
    print('Refresh Token:', token)
    access_token = response.json()['access_token']
    print('Access Token:', access_token)

    if len(token) > 15:
        url = uri
        payload = {'usecli_token': token}
        response2 = requests.post(url, data=payload)

    # Listado de datos de tipos de publicaciones
    url = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/listing_prices?price=100'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
    response2 = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    precios = response2.json()

    for precio in precios:
        print(precio)
else:
    print('Error al obtener el token de acceso:', response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
```

Regarding the document https://developers.mercadolibre.com.ar/es_ar/autenticacion-y-autorizacion
I followed all the steps but I keep receiving this error:

> {"cause":,"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"code_verifier is a required parameter","status":400}

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look for `code_verifier` in the document you link to above.  You've forgotten to include it.

Comment: Yes but it says it is an optional parameter and no information regarding this code_verifier is included

Answer (score 2):

Redo the application on Mercado Livre and disable PKCE in the app's permission options, then you can leave the code_verifier field empty.